# How to change window manager from KDE to Bspwm?

Tags: manjaro

I'm currently using Manjaro Linux 18.1.2 and want to change my desktop environment from KDE to Bspwm. I tried to find find some guides, but failed to. Only some examples for popular managers like XFCE or Gnome, but their examples didn't help. Maybe it's because Bspwn is not that popular.

So can anyone provide quick guide how to do it without reinstalling the whole system?

Answer (score 2):

BSPWM is a window manager, not a desktop environment. What you probably want to know is how to change KDE's default window manager (kwin) to BSPWM.

[see](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/7yle6y/how_to_use_a_different_window_manager_in_plasma/duhllz6/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x)

Basically, install bspwm if you haven't already and create a new executable shell script `wm.sh` in yourhomefile/.config/plasma-workspace/env with the line

```
export KDEWM=/bin/bspwm
```

This is self explanatory but it's setting KDE's default window manager from kwin to bspwm. Restart your PC and you should have bspwm.